# Replace null in a DateTime?[] with DateTime.MaxValue using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, replace, nullable

How can I replace all `DateTime?`s where the date is `null` with `DateTime.MaxValue`?

I have tried:

```
Array.ConvertAll(myDateTimeArray, a => a = a.HasValue ? a : DateTime.MaxValue);
```

and also:

```
myDateTimeArray.Where(a => a == null).ToList().ForEach(a => a = DateTime.MaxValue);
```

After that I want to do something like:

```
DateTime minDate = myDateTimeArray.Min(a => a.Value);
```

but I am getting an `InvalidOperationException` because `a.Value` is `null`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project the dates into a new array using [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx):

```
var newArray = myDateTimeArray.Select(x => x ?? DateTime.MaxValue).ToArray();
```

The [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (`??`) returns the left-hand operand if it is not null, or else it returns the right operand.

Comment: This was exactly what if have been looking for.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
myDateTimeArray = myDateTimeArray.Select(dt => dt ?? DateTime.MaxValue).ToArray();
```

This would replace the entire array, not its individual elements. If you need to replace individual elements, use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: Or use ConvertAll with the same lambda expression.

Comment: The .ToArray() generates a new Array of DateTime (not DateTime?), so it cant be placed in the original array. But the projection was the right way. thx

Answer (score 0):

The [Enumerable.Min Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min.aspx) doesn't have an overload that takes a collection of `DateTime` (or `DateTime?`) values. You can use the [Enumerable.Aggregate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) to implement your own `Min` method:

```
DateTime? result = myDateTimeArray.Where(x => x != null)
                                  .DefaultIfEmpty(null)
                                  .Aggregate((x, y) => x < y ? x : y);
```

This returns `null` if `myDateTimeArray` is empty or all elements in `myDateTimeArray` are `null`, or the minimum `DateTime` value in `myDateTimeArray` otherwise.